# http tunneling can be used to bypass a router port-forward or uPnP?

Tags: c++, http, tunneling

I'm currently working on an application and I would like to know if http tunneling can be used to bypass a router port-forward or uPnP? If so how can it be done and do I need an external server to pass the info to it?

I'm coding in C++ so I would appreciate if the answers refer to this operating language. If not, it's OK because I can redo the code in C++, if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633118/getting-started-with-http-tunneling

Answer (score 1):

Here you will get an [explanation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/webproxysslhttptunnel.aspx) on how it is working. Then you will find plenty of code and libraries on [Punching holes into firewalls](http://sebsauvage.net/punching/index.html). See bottom.